# ng-click stop working when toaster define in service

Tags: angularjs

If I disable noty service it's enable "Show Toast" button ng-click events, and when I going to use noty service it's stop my all ng-click events.

noty service implementation will find into "tempService.js" which basically an implementation of toaster notification message.

Example in below link

http://embed.plnkr.co/9LHH4inRLncWryt7mF1w/

Comment: more source http://plnkr.co/edit/9LHH4inRLncWryt7mF1w

Comment: Check your browser console (F12) - there is an erro there. What is `noty`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your example, check it out [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/23RbummND9Wo2icakout).

The problem was related to how you used Angular modules, please read [this section of the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval).

Basically I put the Angular module declaration into a separate file called `bootstrapper.js`:

```
angular.module('main', ['toaster']);
```

Loaded it right after the third party libraries:

```
<script src="bootstrapper.js"></script>
```

And referenced (retrieved, not created) the Angular module in all the other files this way:

```
angular.module('main')
```